# Cypress cant seem to find any elements inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, cypress

I am trying to access elements within my iframe following the tips listed in this article [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/), but for some reason cypress cannot seem to find anything in the iframe.

Here is my test code

```
describe('example to-do app', () => {
    const getIframeDocument = () => {
        return cy
            .get('iframe[data-cy="iframe"]')
            .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
    }

    const getIframeBody = () => {
        return getIframeDocument()
            .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
            .then(cy.wrap)
    }

    it('finds the root', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/view')
        getIframeBody().get('#root');
    })
});
```

And this is my iframe

`<iframe data-cy="iframe" title="iframe" style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }} src={url} />`

Finally this is what I have in my `cypress.json`

```
{
    "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

This is based on the above article. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin called [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe). After installation, go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and add the following:

```
import 'cypress-iframe';
```

In your test you can directly use :

```
cy.iframe('[data-cy="iframe"]').find('.some-button').should('be.visible').click()
cy.iframe('[data-cy="iframe"]').contains('Some element').should('not.be.visible')
```